# AF_XDP: No packets from multicast although steered on RX-Queue 0

Tags: c, linux, sockets, bpf, xdp-bpf

I am still playing with the AF_XDP socket and my program is still largely based on: https://github.com/xdp-project/xdp-tutorial/tree/master/advanced03-AF_XDP

I now want to receive multiple multicast streams (which works fine the way I register the multicast IPs because I have tested it with the default Linux socket thus I am not sharing the code unless you guys say it is necessary to solve the issue).

Because I don't want to change my program to work on multiple RX-Queues of the NIC just yet (go step by step, but eventually I have to do it to increase throughput) I steered the traffic onto a single RX-Queue with this command:

```
sudo ethtool -N eth20 flow-type udp4 action 0
```

Filter seems to be active:

```
$ sudo ethtool -n eth20
48 RX rings available
Total 1 rules

Filter: 1023
        Rule Type: UDP over IPv4
        Src IP addr: 0.0.0.0 mask: 255.255.255.255
        Dest IP addr: 0.0.0.0 mask: 255.255.255.255
        TOS: 0x0 mask: 0xff
        Src port: 0 mask: 0xffff
        Dest port: 0 mask: 0xffff
        Action: Direct to queue 0
```

But for whatever reason, I receive exactly `0` packets. This is the Kernel-program I am using:

```
struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") xsks_map = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_XSKMAP,
    .key_size = sizeof(int),
    .value_size = sizeof(int),
    .max_entries = 64,  /* Assume netdev has no more than 64 queues */
};

SEC("xdp_sock")
int xdp_sock_prog(struct xdp_md *ctx) {

    int index = ctx->rx_queue_index;

    void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;

    void *pos = data;
    struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr*)(pos);

    if(eth + sizeof(struct ethhdr) <= data_end) {

        if(bpf_ntohs(eth->h_proto) == ETH_P_IP) {
            struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr*)(pos + sizeof(struct ethhdr));

            if(iph + sizeof(struct iphdr) <= data_end) {

                if(iph->protocol == IPPROTO_UDP) {
                    const __u16 iph_sz_in_bytes = iph->ihl * 4;

                    if(iph + iph_sz_in_bytes <= data_end) {
                        struct udphdr *udh = (struct udphdr*)(pos + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + iph_sz_in_bytes);

                        if(udh + sizeof(struct udphdr) <= data_end) {

                            if (bpf_map_lookup_elem(&xsks_map, &index)) {
                                return bpf_redirect_map(&xsks_map, index, 0);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return XDP_PASS;
}
```

Any ideas why?

Edit:

I changed:

```
                    if (bpf_map_lookup_elem(&xsks_map, &index)) {
                        const int ret_val = bpf_redirect_map(&xsks_map, index, 0);
                        bpf_printk("RET-VAL: %d\n", ret_val);
                        return ret_val;
                    }
```

and did

> sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe

which returns:

`ksoftirqd/17-98    [017] ..s. 277979.654041: 0: RET-VAL: 4`

According to the description of `bpf_redirect_map`:

> - Returns  *     **XDP_REDIRECT** on success, or the value of the two
>     lower bits  *     of the **flags* argument on error.

Because `XDP_REDIRECT = 4` I assume this works as expected.

Furthermore, I added this output in the user-space code in `main()` after parsing of command line arguments has happened:

```
printf("RX-Queue: %d\n", cfg.xsk_if_queue);
```

Which indeed returns `0` (so correct RX-Queue is selected).

Edit_2: The strange thing is that I was able to receive a single multicast stream before (which somehow ended up on RX-Queue 0 by accident) but after executing the `ethtool`-command above I am not receiving anything at all. Sounds strange but that's how I observed it.

Edit_3: `sudo ethtool -S eth20` returned: http://ix.io/2cSC

```
$ sudo bpftool prog show
39: cgroup_skb  tag 7be49e3934a125ba  gpl
        loaded_at 2020-02-28T08:00:06+0000  uid 0
        xlated 296B  not jited  memlock 4096B  map_ids 38,39
40: cgroup_skb  tag 2a142ef67aaad174  gpl
        loaded_at 2020-02-28T08:00:06+0000  uid 0
        xlated 296B  not jited  memlock 4096B  map_ids 38,39
41: cgroup_skb  tag 7be49e3934a125ba  gpl
        loaded_at 2020-02-28T08:00:06+0000  uid 0
        xlated 296B  not jited  memlock 4096B  map_ids 40,41
42: cgroup_skb  tag 2a142ef67aaad174  gpl
        loaded_at 2020-02-28T08:00:06+0000  uid 0
        xlated 296B  not jited  memlock 4096B  map_ids 40,41
43: cgroup_skb  tag 7be49e3934a125ba  gpl
        loaded_at 2020-02-28T08:00:06+0000  uid 0
        xlated 296B  not jited  memlock 4096B  map_ids 42,43
44: cgroup_skb  tag 2a142ef67aaad174  gpl
        loaded_at 2020-02-28T08:00:06+0000  uid 0
        xlated 296B  not jited  memlock 4096B  map_ids 42,43
```

Comment: Hmm I can't see any red flag in your program. Checklist to try to pin down... So you checked your program is correctly loaded and attached? That a simple `return XDP_PASS` program passes all packets, a `return XDP_DROP` drops all? That your socket map is filled? That `ctx->rx_queue_index` is effectively 0 (could use `bpf_trace_printk()` to check)? What's the return value from `bpf_redirect_map()`?

Comment: @Qeole I updated my original posting. Unfortunately, I can't just use `XDP_PASS` or  `XDP_DROP` as a Test-program because `libbpf` wouldn't load an AF-XDP socket which does not access any map (take a look at line `506` in `xsk.c` in libbpf: https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf/blob/master/src/xsk.c). But because `bpf_redirect_map()` returns "success" I assume that this works as expected

Comment: Ok, yeah I haven't worked a lot with sockmaps this far. Hmm. Regarding your edit #2, doest that mean that you receive no packet at all even if BPF prog is not present? Also does `ethtool -n eth20` return the filter we expect? I don't remember, can't we get per-queue stats with `ethtool -S`? Maybe worth checking what it says. Also [check run count](https://twitter.com/qeole/status/1110177898269429761) for your program, to make sure it actually runs (but then you see stuff in `trace_pipe` so it probably runs at some point)?

Comment: @Qeole I just rebooted the system to clear the statistics given by `ethtool -S` then ran the program for 6s. I attached the output to the original posting. I don't know right now how I can get `bpftool` on Debian

Comment: @Qeole I also added the output for `bpftool prog show`. Really interesting Twitter page btw

Comment: Thanks! Yeah [no package](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=896165) for Debian so far, you'd have to build from source. Hmm you apparently have a number of packets dropped or redirected with XDP (`rx0_xdp_drop: 11250292`, `rx0_xdp_redirect: 2048`). How are you trying to see them on your socket? Could it be that the bug is in the user space program? Also `bpftool prog show` doesn't show your programs, they were probably not attached when you ran the command (the `cgroup_skb` programs we see were created [by systemd](https://kailueke.gitlab.io/tags/bpf/)).

Comment: @Qeole Oh, I just started to remove the keys from the maps shown by `bpftool prog show` because I thought they were leftovers from previous programs I started and could therefore interfere with each other.  What do you mean with `How are you trying to see them on your socket?`. There certainly could be a bug in the user space but I didn't change much. Only added a generic linux socket which sends the multicast IGMP messages. I got the `bpftool`-package from here: https://github.com/xdp-project/xdp-tutorial/blob/master/setup_dependencies.org#recommended-tools

Comment: Haha, I created that .deb package :). I meant, what do you mean by `I receive exactly 0 packets`? How do you tell?

Comment: @Qeole There is a `poll()` call in https://github.com/xdp-project/xdp-tutorial/blob/master/advanced03-AF_XDP/af_xdp_user.c which never returns

Comment: Ok, hmm I don't really have any more ideas, if you don't get an answer here you may want to try other channels (#xdp on Freenode on IRC, GitHub repo for the tutorial, xdp-newbies mailing list...)

Comment: @Qeole Thank you so much for your help. I will ask on freenode!

Answer (score 0):

There was indeed a problem in my user-space code. I polled the filedescriptor of the socket even though I disabled polling. Because of that it never returned.